# listview addheaderView headview‘s textview click event do not work

Tags: android, listview

android listview add headerView ,but the textView's onclicklestener in the header item does not work .
my english is not well. thanks.

code in myFragment

```
ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header, list, true);
list.addHeaderView(headerView);
list.setAdapter(musicBaseAdapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RedActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("rank", position);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
headerView.setOnClickListener(new ViewGroup.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.text1:
                    log.d("text1");
                    break;
                case R.id.text2:
                    log.d("text2");
                    break;
                case R.id.text3:
                    break;
                case R.id.text4:
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

when i click the textview in headeritem,it nothing changed.
how can i set the click event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is you are assuming that click events for the child `View`s in your header `ViewGroup` will receive the group's click events.

This is not true. In that click listener you have, the value of `View v` will only ever be the `headerView` instance.

What you want is to attach click listeners to each of your header's views.

Ie.

```
headerView.findViewById(R.id.text1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        log.d("text1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works . You need to set listner for  each view if you want to get separate click on each . There can be multiple way to do it . You can try following.

Let your Fragment implement `OnClickListener`. and set `onClick` for each item. Below is an example .

```
class MFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.text1:
                log.d("text1");
                break;
            case R.id.text2:
                log.d("text2");
                break;
            case R.id.text3:
                break;
            case R.id.text4:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And set Listener .

```
ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header, list, true);
    headerView.findViewById(R.id.text1).setOnClickListener(MFragment.this);
    headerView.findViewById(R.id.text2).setOnClickListener(MFragment.this);
    headerView.findViewById(R.id.text3).setOnClickListener(MFragment.this);
    headerView.findViewById(R.id.text4).setOnClickListener(MFragment.this);
    list.addHeaderView(headerView);
    list.setAdapter(musicBaseAdapter);
```